# getting a power-set that uses all characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

say I have a string "abc" I'm trying to return a set of subsets similar to a powerset, but the sets need to use all three letters.

[['a,'b','c], ['ab', 'c'], ['a', 'bc'], ['abc']]

also what would you call this because can't call it a powerset?

Answer (score 1):

Super-Naive and Lazy Solution:

```
var str = "abc";
var set = new Set();

for(var j = 0; j < str.length; ++j){
  for(var i = 1; i < str.length + 1; ++i){
    var substr = str.substring(j, i);
    if(substr != ""){
      set.add(substr);
    }
  }
}

console.log(set);
```

JavaScript provides the "Set" collection which allows you to store unique elements.
Of course, this solution is O(n^2), there are other ways to do it that would be more efficient but here you have it!

Comment: I did this in a hurry. I know. Its horrible but it can give you the basics to come up with a better solution.

Comment: its better than down voting my question for no reason. appreciate the efforts.